# Is there a way to create a std::vector of dynamically allocated arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, vector, allocation

For example, is it possible to have a std::vector of these arrays?

```
int *test1 = new int[10];
int *test2 = new int[20];
int *test3 = new int[3];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
std::vector<int*> vints;
vints.push_back(new int[10]);
vints.push_back(new int[20]);
vints.push_back(new int[3]);
```

But there is a problem: the vector can't remember the size of each *dynamically* allocated arrays.

So better use `std:map` as:

```
std::map<int, int*> arrayMap;
arrayMap[10] = new int[10];
arrayMap[20] = new int[20];
arrayMap[3] = new int[3];
```

The key of this map tells the size of the corresponding *dynamically* allocated array.

Yet better still is : vector of vector as:

```
std::vector<vector<int> > vecArray;
```

I would prefer the last approach, unless I've strong reason to go for the earlier ones, i.e container of *dynamically* allocated arrays.

Comment: I don't need to remember the size of the arrays, I have that stored elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @Pig Head: How do you associate them? Bette would to use `std::map` then!

Comment: @Nawaz And what if there are several arrays whith same size?? This case you will have memory leak in your program.

Comment: @Mihran: Ofcourse, the `std::map` wouldn't work. But the question is, do I know all the possible cases? No. So its just to give few ideas. BTW, is this the reason for your downvote?

Comment: The question is "is it possible to have a std::vector of these arrays?", and it would be better to give "good" new idea if you decided. Yes this is the reason.

Comment: @Mihran: How do you "good" without knowing the use-cases? Did you say he is going to have several arrays with same size? Also, does my answer not contain other solutions, and did I not explicitly say "I would prefer vector of vector approach"?

Comment: Ok question to you? Will you do such thing that you suggested? If Yes, I will remove my downvote, otherwise this is bad suggestion.

Comment: @Mihran: What such thing? Did you read the line where I said **"I would prefer vector of vector, unless...."**? I wouldn't even choose *dynamically* allocated arrays, for most of my problems.

Comment: I mean will you ever use map of dynamic array?
Yes I saw that, but also you suggested the way which is not answer of his question, this means that the suggestion should at least be good one.

Comment: @Mihran: The real question you should ask this: "will you ever use vector of dynamic array?"... Once you ask this, you will immediately understand why I brought `map` into the picture... and then why I immediately came up with `vector of vector` and explicitly I said I would prefer `vector of vector` after saying about vector/map of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, but why not just use `vector<vector<int>>` ?  More flexible and less trouble.

If you insist on using arrays, `shared_array` in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) could be helpful in reducing the manual work in managing the array memory.

Comment: `scoped_array` can't go into a std::vector, alas.

Comment: I don't really need any more flexibility than arrays have, what I'm doing is very simple.

Comment: Then it is even more simple if you use `vector`s.  Every `new` you code up introduces extra exception handling questions and memory management complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. But since what you need is simple, make it simple :

```
std::vector <std::vector<int> > myArrayVector(numberOfArrays);
myArrayVector[0].resize(10);
myArrayVector[1].resize(20);
myArrayVector[2].resize(3);
```

Wherever you need to have an int*, use &myArrayVector[i][0], where i is the array index.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Try this.

```
vector<int*> vec;
vec.push_back(test1);
vec.push_back(test2);
vec.push_back(test3);
```

**Edit:**
Do not forget release the memory before your vector goes out of the scope.

```
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
    delete [] vec[i];
}
```

Comment: A caveat is advisable about releasing the memory by hand, or else it is leaked when `vec` goes out of scope.